# Getting error FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Opportunity/Account ID: id value of incorrect type: a4tS00000008dtBIAQ: [WhatId] during task creation

Tags: tasks

I am getting this Salesforce Exception:

> "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Opportunity/Account ID: id value of
>   incorrect type: a4tS00000008dtBIAQ: [WhatId]"

while trying to create a Task on custom object using Apex code.

I am storing Object id in to ID field like `ID whatId = record.id;` and setting it in Task object whatId field.

I am not able to add Task on custom object using object Tab. I am not getting any option to create task on that object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit your custom object and check the 'allow activities' checkbox. This should solve your problem.